# Recieved an Rejection email form google but my app is still listed as "in review"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, publish, review

maybe someone can help me with this issue. I submitted an App to the app review yesterday morning. Just a couple hours later i received an email from Google. My app has been rejected. I want to change my app an resubmit ist but in the goole play console my app is still listed as "in review".

Is this a normal and am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this happened.

even though the console show `in review`, your app has been rejected.

So, my recommendation is to release new version of the app.

Comment: Thanks. It took a while but the status has changed now. The next time i'll try your suggestion.